# Optimize the algorithm to merge text nodes with decorations

Tags: javascript, typescript, tiptap

I need help figuring out how to merge two arrays of nodes with decorations. I have a VERY inefficient algorithm that works, but I need something better or any ideas.

I have two arrays of such text nodes. In general each node consists of text and text decorations (color, font styles etc.) and `from`, `to` indexes. I want to merge these two arrays so that text would remain the same but the decorations would be merged.

Here's my current algorithm that iterates through each letter of the content, checks if the letter has any decorations and creates a separate node for the letter with all the decorations:

```
const getDecorationsByIndex = (nodes, index) => {
  const foundNodes: any[] = [];

  nodes.forEach(node => {
    if (index >= node.from && index < node.to) {
      foundNodes.push(node);
    }
  });

  return foundNodes.flatMap(node => node.textData?.decorations || []);
};

const mergeNodes = (nodes1, nodes2, content) => {
  const mergedNodes = [...content].map((s, index) => {
    const decorations1 = getDecorationsByIndex(nodes1, index);
    const decorations2 = getDecorationsByIndex(nodes2, index);

    return {
      id: '',
      nodes: [],
      type: Node_Type.TEXT,
      textData: {
        decorations: [...decorations1, ...decorations2],
        text: s,
      },
    };
  });

  return mergedNodes;
};
```

As an example let's take a simple text `def` which has various decorations, from color to font weight.

Each of the arrays fully represent the text.
This one adds some boldness:

```
[
  {
      "type": "TEXT",
      "id": "",
      "nodes": [],
      "textData": {
          "text": "de",
          "decorations": [
              {
                  "type": "BOLD",
                  "fontWeightValue": 700
              }
          ]
      },
      "from": 0,
      "to": 2
  },
  {
      "type": "TEXT",
      "id": "",
      "nodes": [],
      "textData": {
          "text": "f",
          "decorations": []
      },
      "from": 2,
      "to": 3
  }
]
```

The second array adds colors:

```
    [
  {
      "id": "",
      "nodes": [],
      "type": "TEXT",
      "textData": {
          "decorations": [
              {
                  "type": "COLOR",
                  "colorData": {
                      "foreground": "#d73a49"
                  }
              }
          ],
          "text": "def"
      },
      "from": 0,
      "to": 3
  }
]
```

The result should be:

```
[
  {
      "type": "TEXT",
      "id": "",
      "nodes": [],
      "textData": {
          "text": "de",
          "decorations": [
              {
                  "type": "BOLD",
                  "fontWeightValue": 700
              },{
                  "type": "COLOR",
                  "colorData": {
                      "foreground": "#d73a49"
                  }
              }
          ]
      },
      "from": 0,
      "to": 2
  },
  {
      "type": "TEXT",
      "id": "",
      "nodes": [],
      "textData": {
          "text": "f",
          "decorations": [{
                  "type": "COLOR",
                  "colorData": {
                      "foreground": "#d73a49"
                  }
              }]
      },
      "from": 2,
      "to": 3
  }
]
```

The result should be one array of these nodes that in the end would have the same text with all the decorations. Help me either optimize my algorithm or point me to right direction how should I approach merging these nodes. Thank you.

Comment: The decorations have `text` properties, but then your merge function also adds `text` properties from `contents`.  What is the practical meaning of that?

Comment: @trincot Yes, because I go letter by letter, that's the bad part here. Ideally I would want to use only the `textData` from each node to do all the merging/splitting.

Comment: Basically the `content` would be if I go node by node and merge all the text together.

Comment: Hmmm... so if you get an answer that goes node by node, it will not serve your purpose? Can you provide the expected output for the sample input you have given? I don't know what to do with `contents`.

Comment: What if there is a contradiction between the texts from one node and another overlapping node?

Comment: I've added a simpler example with the text "def". The "def" word itself is red and the "de" part of it is in bold. I would want to have these two arrays merged so that I would have two nodes: "de" as bold and red, and "f" as only red.

Comment: It looks to me you shouldn't store the texts a properties, but have one overall text string. The from/to indications uniquely define what the substring is. This way you cannot have inconsistent data.

Comment: That's the whole idea, I want to merge the decorations that overlap. The text always should remain the same in the end. Just the amount of nodes needed to apply all the required decorations would vary

Comment: I mean what if the node with "f" has "g" instead. Then it conflicts with the text "def"... You have redundancy.

Comment: That's the way these nodes are constructed. I can have the whole text as one string (I pass it to function as `content`), but how would it help me?

Comment: The nodes are the source of truth for the text, they won't have any strings that shouldn't be there and the interval always shows the correct position of this substring in the context of the whole content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255444/discussion-between-developer1-and-trincot).

Comment: Can you explain how `id`, `nodes`, `type` are to be derived during the merge? Or are they hardcoded? If not, what if two overlapping nodes have conflicting data for any of these properties?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the from/to information to sort nodes by their index (so you need to duplicate the nodes, once for taking their `from` property, once for the `to` property). Then sort that, and iterate in that order to keep track of which decorations are active or not.

Before starting you could also collect the substrings and rebuild a string from that. This can then be used in the main algorithm to slice it up again.

```js
const Node_Type = { TEXT: 3 };

// Helper function to toggle a set member
const toggle = (set, member) => !set.delete(member) && set.add(member);

const extractText = (nodes) =>
    // Reconstruct text from the nodes (there should be no inconsistency)
    nodes.reduce((acc, node) => {
        acc.length = Math.max(acc.length, node.from);
        acc.splice(node.from, node.to - node.from, ...node.textData.text);
        return acc;
    }, []).map(ch => ch ?? " ").join("");

const mergeNodes = (nodes1, nodes2) => {
    const nodes = nodes1.concat(nodes2);
    const text = extractText(nodes);
    const activeNodes = new Set;
    return nodes.flatMap(node => [[node.from, node], [node.to, node]])
                 .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
                 .map(([from, node], i, toggles) => {
        toggle(activeNodes, node); // Activate or deactivate a decoration
        const to = toggles[i+1]?.[0] ?? text.length;
        if (from === to || !activeNodes.size) return; // Nothing to generate here
        return {
            id: '',
            nodes: [],
            type: Node_Type.TEXT,
            textData: {
               decorations: Array.from(activeNodes, ({textData: {decorations}}) => decorations).flat(), 
               text: text.slice(from, to),
            },
            from,
            to
        };
    }).filter(Boolean); // Exclude the undefined entries
}

// Sample input
const a = [{
    "type": "TEXT", "id": "", "nodes": [],
    "textData": { "text": "de", "decorations": [{"type": "BOLD","fontWeightValue": 700}] },
    "from": 0, "to": 2
}, {
    "type": "TEXT", "id": "", "nodes": [],
    "textData": { "text": "f someFoo", "decorations": []},
    "from": 2, "to": 11
}];

const b = [{
    "id": "", "nodes": [], "type": "TEXT",
    "textData": {
        "decorations": [{"type": "COLOR","colorData": {"foreground": "#d73a49"}}],
        "text": "def"
    },
    "from": 0, "to": 3
}, {
    "id": "", "nodes": [], "type": "TEXT",
    "textData": { "decorations": [], "text": " "},
    "from": 3, "to": 4
}, {
    "id": "", "nodes": [], "type": "TEXT",
    "textData": {
        "decorations": [{"type": "COLOR", "colorData": {"foreground": "#6f42c1"}}],
        "text": "someFoo"
    },
    "from": 4, "to": 11
}];

console.log(mergeNodes(a, b));
```

Note that the shared decorations are not cloned, so some nodes will have the same object references in their `decorations` array. This means that if you would mutate a decoration, it would apply to all nodes that share it. If you prefer to have it work differently, you should clone decorations in the process.